# Page cannot be reached in Google Rich snippet test

Tags: googlebot, crawl-errors

When i test my webpage in google rich test, it say page cannot be reached. My website is on shopify so i guess there should be no issue from server side.
I need your help please... I cannot figure out why this cannot be reached.Page cannot be reached in Google Rich snippet test.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! These things happen from time to time, even to Google. If your site can be reached by users, just try again later. Sometimes these types of errors can be seen for a few days. There are probably a thousand (slight exaggeration) reasons why this happens. It could be one or more of many. If your site is working okay, do not panic, be patient, it will all work out in the end. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same trouble with bot user agents of the test tool. The site at its own is successfully loaded.

To debug it i would do the following:

Afaik robots.txt is case-sensitive. I don't exactly know, whether case-sensitivy should be maintained on naming of user agents. In case of yes, your robots.txt contains an error: Google [defines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596) user agent of adsbot as `AdsBot-Google` - you write it as `adsbot-google`. I would change it at first to become d'accord with Google.